# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined in MERN

Tags: reactjs, express, response, router, mern

So in my MERN project in my router, I am trying to send some data so I can get afterwards on my react component so I can use that data.

But I get this error when I run my code: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
  const Accomodation = require('../models/accomodation')
    Accomodation.findOne({email: req.session.passport.user}).lean().exec((err, user, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, null);
        }  

        if (user) {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: user.accomcate
          })
      }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.exec` accepts two arguments `err` and `res` , you are using three which is causing the error.